# Is it possible to control DTR and/or RTS for a serial process (serial-term)?

Tags: process

I create a serial port process with `(serial-term)`, or the underlying `(make-serial-process ...)`. Is it possible to control the DTR and/or RTS pins for the port from within Emacs?

Looking at the source code (version 26.2, May 2020), it looks like the answer is "no", but I'm wondering if I'm missing a general ioctl() mechanism or something else.

Context:  embedded development.  Many target devices (e.g. Arduino) use DTR or RTS for a hard reset.

Comment: IIRC arduino modes used perl to do that. I'll look at it later

Comment: I can certainly do it with an external process/command, but I was looking for a way to do it within emacs to avoid race conditions on reading the data after reset.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing in vanilla emacs. There are stuff for using some embebbed platforms with control over serial beyond communication control, but AFAIK again, doing it externally.